# TensorFlow error ,NotFoundError：dlopen(.../roi_pooling.so, 6): image not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, faster-rcnn

I am a beginner in machine learning and I want to clone Faster RCNN approach to training my dataset.

I try to run Faster_RCNN_TF from this source：

https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF#installation-sufficient-for-the-demo and I got this error can't solve.

```
...line 60, in load_op_library lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: dlopen(/Users/anthony/Faster-RCNN_TF/tools/../lib/roi_pooling_layer/roi_pooling.so, 6): image not found
```

Environment(virtual environment):

Run on the 2021 Mac m1 chip

macOS：11.6.1 Python：3.7.11

TensorFlow：2.0.0

TensorFlow install form anaconda

GPU model and memory：M1 GPU,16 GB RAM

Bazel version：N/A

CUDA/cuDNN：N/A

---

I try to search this error on website, might I required to install some configure files ? but I don't know how to do it, sorry I am fairly new on this.
I am appreciate any ideal.

Comment: Which sections are you having issues with? Was it the installation, demo, or training model?

Comment: when I run demo, train_net, test_net these three program had same error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I finished installing the environment(version: python, TensorFlow...), I try run train.py then I get this error. At present, I try to execute it on the Mac in a different way.